# Number of 2x2 submatrices in a nxn matrix.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I need to find the number of $2 \times 2$ submatrices in a $n \times n$ matrix. I think I can do it combinatorically but I'm having trouble making sure the matrices are $2\times 2$. Any help would be appreciated! I thought maybe $\binom{n}{2}^{2}$ but that does not seem right.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct. There are ${n \choose 2} $ choices for a pair of rows and the same number of choices for a pair of columns.

Comment: If $A$ is a $n\times n$, $n\geq 2$ matrix with all entries the same, there is only one 2$\times 2$ submatrix no ? How do you count them ?

Comment: @JPA we can assume that the submatrices with different positions are different from each other. If the problem is solved the way you ask, it will depend heavily on the value of each element in the matrix